# How can the automatically entered (input) values with a comma (3,14) be changed to a dot (3.14) in python?

Tags: python

For example the part of my code.  After that, the interface comes out with the entered (input) values

```
def RDTT(): 

    global zp,zL,zD1,zR1,zD2,zR2


    p = float(ui.lineEdit_51.text())   
    zp = p
    L = float(ui.lineEdit_31.text())   
    zL = L
    D1 = float(ui.lineEdit_57.text())   
    zD1 = D1
    if D1 <= 0:
        messagebox.showerror("Ошибка")
        return
    R1 = D1 / 2   
    zR1 = R1
    D2 = float(ui.lineEdit_32.text())   
    zD2 = D2
    if D2 <= 0:
        messagebox.showerror("Ошибка")
        return
    if D1 >= D2:
        messagebox.showerror("Ошибка")
        return
    R2 = D2 / 2   
    zR2 = R2
```

it is necessary that the program automatically changes the entered values from commas to dots. For example 3,14 should change to 3.14. And did not give an error

Answer (score 1):

Replace the comma with a dot in Python using the `replace()` method. For Example:

`p = float(ui.lineEdit_51.text().replace(',', '.'))`

You can use this method for all input values in your code.